# How many "&&" can an "if" statement handle?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
if @if_tannin_true && @if_acid_true && @if_alcohol_true && @if_body_true #I would like to add this: && @if_fruit_true #&& @if_fruit_character_true && @if_non_fruit_true && @if_organic_earth_true && @if_inorganic_earth_true && @if_wood_true

  y = 0
  while y < @grapes[i].testables.count
    @result << @grapes[i].testables[y].name
    y+=1
  end
end
```

I realized that an if statement using four "&&"s works fine, but one with a fifth  will not. How could I handle that?

---

Edit: It now works. I just restarted the server. Good to know that we can use as many "&&"s as needed.

Comment: No need to inject: `[@a,@b,...].all?` does the job.

Comment: @user1934428, I think you should write this as an answer.

Comment: "Now looking to improve code readability." - this changes the initial question and invalidates the already given answers. Make sure to avoid such cases and ask a new question. Be aware, that asking  for improving code readability might not be gladly met on StackOverflow. You'll be better of asking on, say, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko : I didn't understand this sentence by the user as a request to get suggestions for improving readability, but that he thinks that this is the next task to do. Of course we can't read his mind though....

Comment: @Ilya: Well, it is not really an answer to the original question (this would more likely something like *You can happily write && operands until Ruby exhausts all its available memory*), so I think I leave it as a comment.

Comment: @user1934428 you might be right and I mistaken this sentence as such request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting question!

## Short answer

Between 5000 and 10000, depending on your system.

## Theory

You could create a string with many `true && true && true && ...` and evaluate it.

- If it returns `true`, you can add some more `&&`s.
- If it fails with a `SystemStackError` or even a segmentation fault, you'll need to remove some `&&`s.

Since it can crash, you need to write 2 different scripts in order to prevent the main loop from also crashing.

[`bsearch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) finds the limit as fast as possible, without having to iterate over every single possiblity.

## Code

#### `many_ands.rb`

```
# many_ands.rb
many_ands = (['true'] * (ARGV[0].to_i + 1)).join(' && ')
eval(many_ands)
```

#### `max_ands.rb`

```
big_number = 100_000

max_ands = (0..big_number).bsearch do |i|
  print "Testing #{i} : "
  result = system("ruby many_ands.rb #{i}")
  puts result ? 'Fine' : "Too many &&'s"
  puts
  !result
end

puts "Max number of &&'s without exception : #{max_ands - 1}"
```

It outputs:

```
Testing 50000 : many_ands.rb:2:in `eval': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from many_ands.rb:2:in `<main>'
Too many &&'s

Testing 25000 : many_ands.rb:2:in `eval': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from many_ands.rb:2:in `<main>'
Too many &&'s

Testing 12500 : many_ands.rb:2:in `eval': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from many_ands.rb:2:in `<main>'
Too many &&'s

Testing 6250 : many_ands.rb:2:in `eval': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from many_ands.rb:2:in `<main>'
Too many &&'s

Testing 3125 : Fine

Testing 4688 : Fine

Testing 5469 : many_ands.rb:2:in `eval': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from many_ands.rb:2:in `<main>'
Too many &&'s

Testing 5079 : Fine

Testing 5274 : many_ands.rb:2:in `eval': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from many_ands.rb:2:in `<main>'
Too many &&'s

Testing 5177 : many_ands.rb:2:in `eval': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from many_ands.rb:2:in `<main>'
Too many &&'s

Testing 5128 : many_ands.rb:2:in `eval': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from many_ands.rb:2:in `<main>'
Too many &&'s

Testing 5104 : Fine

Testing 5116 : Fine

Testing 5122 : Fine

Testing 5125 : Fine

Testing 5127 : many_ands.rb:2:in `eval': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from many_ands.rb:2:in `<main>'
Too many &&'s

Testing 5126 : many_ands.rb:2:in `eval': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from many_ands.rb:2:in `<main>'
Too many &&'s

Max number of &&'s without exception : 5125
```

It depends on the system : On my Linux VM, it returned 5125. On a server, it returned 7930.

Results vary a bit from one run to the other, even on the same system.

## eval or &&?

Where does the limitation come from? Is it from the string length passed to `eval` or does it come from the number of `&&`s?

By modifying `many_ands.rb`, we now pass a big string to eval with many small expressions instead of one huge `&&` expression:

```
many_ands = (['true'] * (ARGV[0].to_i + 1)).join(';')
eval(many_ands)
```

The main loop outputs:

```
Testing 5000000 : Fine

Testing 7500000 : Fine

Testing 8750000 : Fine

Testing 9375000 : Fine

Testing 9687500 : Fine

Testing 9843750 : Fine

Testing 9921875 : Fine

Testing 9960938 : Fine

Testing 9980469 : Fine

Testing 9990235 : Fine

Testing 9995118 : Fine

Testing 9997559 : Fine

Testing 9998780 : Fine

Testing 9999390 : Fine

Testing 9999695 : Fine

Testing 9999848 : Fine

Testing 9999924 : Fine

Testing 9999962 : Fine

Testing 9999981 : Fine

Testing 9999991 : Fine

Testing 9999996 : Fine

Testing 9999998 : Fine

Testing 9999999 : Fine

Testing 10000000 : Fine

max_and.rb:11:in `<main>': undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

It seems the limitation does come from the number of `&&`s in the expression. With 10 million `true;...`, the string passed to `eval` is 50MB big.

Comment: Good answer. But the result should be 5126, not 5127. No? It also has to be shown that the errors caused are not due to other factors (such as the limit of the length of a string that can be passed to `eval`, and so on).

Comment: @sawa: Excellent points, thanks. My code actually had 2 off-by-one errors, but I wrongly thought they cancelled each other. I'm also investigating your comment about `eval`.

Comment: @sawa: `eval` seems to work fine with huge strings, for example with 10_000_000 of `true;true;true;...`

Comment: Great addition to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

> I realized that the `if` statement using 4 `&&` works fine but when I
>   start adding a fifth it will not.

There is no limit to the number of `&&` you use in a statement. So it will work with 4, 5, 100.

It fails because some of the conditions are falsey.

Comment: Probably there is a limit, but no practical limit.

Comment: @sawa: Indeed. Around 5150 on my system. :)

Answer (score 3):

`&&` is a boolean operator. There is no theoretical limit as to how many if statements it can hold.

Using lots in a single statement could be considered a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) in Ruby, but there's no technical reason why you cannot do it.

What error are you getting?

Comment: Would you suggest another code perhaps a switch statement to improve the code readability ?

Comment: The issue is not about the number of if statements, it is about the number of the conjunction operators.